# How do i list application icons displayed on Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: python, windows-10, taskbar

I am trying to write code that will center icons located on taskbar but to do this i need
number of icons.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKxEX.png)

Acording to image above i want to get list of 6 icons

Comment: Pywinauto may be useful https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html

Comment: You could also try counting the files in %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar but there may be duplicates in there or icons that don't show up.